# Stax considers Text+CDATA+Text to be a single CHARACTERS section

Tags: java, xml, cdata, stax, woodstox

Using Stax, I'm surprised to find that an XML block such as:

```
<badger>
    <![CDATA[Text about a badger]]>
</badger>
```

is treated as if it were:

```
START_ELEMENT (badger)
CHARACTERS (        Text about a badger    )
END_ELEMENT (badger)
```

That is, the CDATA and the surrounding text are flattened into one text element. There is no CDATA element detected.

Is this correct behaviour? How can I separate the whitespace from the CDATA?

I am using the woodstox implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the woodstox implementation, but could [this bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/STAX-14), resolved in 2006, still be a factor? **Are you setting the optional [report-cdata-event property](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/STAX-14)?**

(See also [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/axis-cvs@ws.apache.org/msg04056.html) about a similar problem.)

Comment: @Synesso: Are you setting the report-cdata-event property? (See link in answer.)

Comment: Note that bug you referred was for Stax reference implementation, not Woodstox, so this is not the cause when using Woodstox. It would make sense for RI of course.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you have property 'XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING' set to true (or, are using Woodstox 3.2 that had it enabled by default -- which is not the default stax specs suggest, i.e. was a minor bug). This forces both conversion of CDATA into CHARACTERS, and coalesces adjacent text segments if any.

Other than this, Woodstox does report CDATA sections as distinct; but Stax specification has some 'interesting' requirements for convesion -- members of the expert group seemed to dislike idea of CDATA being handled any different from CHARACTERS.

So: if you do want to get them reported separate, make sure to disable IS_COALESCING:

```
inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Answer (score 3):

CDATA isn't an element; it's an escape mechanism that tells the XML parser not to bother looking for nested tags within that section. This is useful for text that contains characters like < and &, to avoid tediously escaping them all individually, or because there's some other reason that normal escape sequences won't work.

Comment: However, Stax supports CDATA events. What is this for, if not to detect CDATA elements?

Comment: @Synesso: This answer has a good point... CDATA markup is explicitly excluded from the XML Infoset (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#omitted), so in terms of standardized use of XML, and compatibility with tools, it's better not to rely on CDATA markup to signify a meaningful distinction.

Comment: Thanks LarsH. Unfortunately the XML documents are not under my control.

Comment: This comment isn't for Synesso, as his comment was long ago, but just for future discussion... There is always some degree of control, even if it's just veto power. Yes, there are times when you just have to work with the input you're given. I've been there. But there are obviously extreme examples where you are given broken input and an unreasonable assignment to work with them. If the input document were empty, and you were asked to get data out, you would rightly say "No can do." This question is not so extreme, but the example illustrates that there are limits to "not under my control."